# No puedo alinear el h1 p y botón en el centro den carrusel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

He estado haciendo un ejercicio y no logro centrar los h1 ni los p ni los botones dentro del carrusel. Estoy trabajando por primera vez en bootstrap y asumo que debe ser por eso> Pero no encuentro el error. He usado la clase **d-flex align-items-center** pero aún  nada. Acá les dejo parte del código a ver si alguien puede saber lo que pasa. También he tratado de utilizar clases internas pero no me toma nada de lo que escribo allí

```
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">    
            <img class="d-block w-100 " src="../starter-code/img/slider-1.jpg" alt="overlay">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-lg-block">
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis temporibus accusamus dolor
                    repellat doloremque eaque dolores eos ex magnam libero animi nulla praesentium laudantium
                    modi, ut sit fugit vitae rem?</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">READ MORE</button>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="../starter-code/img/slider-2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-lg-block" >
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis temporibus accusamus dolor
                    repellat doloremque eaque dolores eos ex magnam libero animi nulla praesentium laudantium
                    modi, ut sit fugit vitae rem?</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">READ MORE</button>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="../starter-code/img/slider-3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-lg-block" >
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis temporibus accusamus dolor
                    repellat doloremque eaque dolores eos ex magnam libero animi nulla praesentium laudantium
                    modi, ut sit fugit vitae rem?</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">READ MORE</button>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="../starter-code/img/slider-4.jpg" alt="Fourth slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-lg-block" >
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis temporibus accusamus dolor
                    repellat doloremque eaque dolores eos ex magnam libero animi nulla praesentium laudantium
                    modi, ut sit fugit vitae rem?</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">READ MORE</button>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap** posiciona a los elementos `carousel-caption` con las reglas `position: absolute` y `bottom: 20px`, lo que provoca que los `<h1>`, `<p>` y `<button>` que tienen dentro, se posicionen en la parte inferior de cada diapositiva. Si quieres que salgan centrados verticalmente te bastaría con sobreescribir ese `bottom: 20px` por un `bottom: 45%` (aproximadamente, puedes ajustarlo para acomodarlo a tu gusto).

```css
.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 45% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">    
            <img class="d-block w-100 " src="https://www.affinity-petcare.com/advance/sites/default/files/field/image/diarrea_en_gatitos_1.jpg" alt="overlay">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-lg-block">
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis temporibus accusamus dolor
                    repellat doloremque eaque dolores eos ex magnam libero animi nulla praesentium laudantium
                    modi, ut sit fugit vitae rem?</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">READ MORE</button>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://www.affinity-petcare.com/advance/sites/default/files/field/image/diarrea_en_gatitos_1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-lg-block" >
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis temporibus accusamus dolor
                    repellat doloremque eaque dolores eos ex magnam libero animi nulla praesentium laudantium
                    modi, ut sit fugit vitae rem?</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">READ MORE</button>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.affinity-petcare.com/advance/sites/default/files/field/image/diarrea_en_gatitos_1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-lg-block" >
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis temporibus accusamus dolor
                    repellat doloremque eaque dolores eos ex magnam libero animi nulla praesentium laudantium
                    modi, ut sit fugit vitae rem?</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">READ MORE</button>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.affinity-petcare.com/advance/sites/default/files/field/image/diarrea_en_gatitos_1.jpg" alt="Fourth slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-lg-block" >
                <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis temporibus accusamus dolor
                    repellat doloremque eaque dolores eos ex magnam libero animi nulla praesentium laudantium
                    modi, ut sit fugit vitae rem?</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">READ MORE</button>
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Para poder apreciar el centrado se ha de reproducir el ejemplo a pantalla completa debido a la clase `d-none` que tienes puesta en los `.carousel-caption`.

**Comentario:**

Posicionar con `!important` no es aconsejable, en su lugar aconsejo dotar a la regla de mayor especifidad. Tan solo lo uso para ejemplificar.